# How to configure Prism with Nuxt

Tags: node.js, webpack, nuxt.js, prismjs

How can I configure Prism to work with Nuxt? I added it as a vendor in the `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
// * Build configuration

build: {
  // * You can extend webpack config here
  vendor: ['axios', 'prismjs'],

  extend(config, ctx) {
    if (ctx.isServer) {
      config.externals = [
        nodeExternals({
          whitelist: [/^vuetify/]
        })
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my page in the script section I import it:

```
<script>
import Prism from'prismjs';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      post: {}
    };
  },
// more data...
```

How can I use it then? I've tried calling it in mounted but it doesn't work. No errors are returned but it doesn't change anything on site.

```
mounted() {
  Prism.highlightAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be working, just forgot about including css styles.